# The mystery of the Strunk & White badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Where did my Strunk & White badge go? In the previous version of MO, it was awarded to whomever edited 100 posts... Now, it's awarded to whomever edits 80 posts. I'd recently acquired it, but it is nowhere to be found in the list of badges the community has bestowed upon yours truly any longer. As [David Roberts](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/4177/david-roberts) said in a thread of a similar persuasion, it's not that I'm of the badge-driven type of user; I'm just a wee bit curious about the whereabouts of my hard-earned Strunk & White badge.

Comment: But we have the Copy Editor badge, which I think I'll have a crack at :-)

Comment: Also, note that meta has a separate badge system to the main site. But even your main profile page http://mathoverflow.net/users/1593/j-h-s?tab=badges&sort=recent doesn't have it. Hmmm..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The logic behind the Strunk & White (and the Copy Editor) badge has changed slightly in 2011 (thus after the split between MO and the SE network). See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80260/115866) on MSO for details.

The changed logic means that fewer edits count towards these badges, which is why the thresholds were lowered. By the old logic, you had over 100 edits that counted, but by the new logic you do not have 80 yet. I checked the data: to be precise, you have 77 eligible edits at the time I write this, so it won't be long until you get it back :)